# SQL SSMS Select clause with 2 where functions for same field

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, where-clause

I want to find customers who have purchased both a piece of fruit and a piece of chocolate in the same purchase. My data looks like this:

```
ID         purchase_date    product
22212      2021-06-03       Fruit
111999     2021-06-03       Fruit
111999     2021-06-03       Chocolate
56727      2019-05-03       Bread
30726      2019-05-03       Fruit
30761      2019-05-03       Chocolate
53899      2019-05-03       Fruit
```

I want this:

```
  ID         purchase_date
  111999     2021-06-03
```

I have tried a select function with a where clause, but It isn't returning any record. Any ideas?

```
SELECT ID, purchase_date
From dbo.mytable
where product='Fruit' AND product='Chocolate'
Group by ID, purchase_date
```

EDIT- does anyone know how I might find people who only bought fruit in a transaction?

Comment: *"It isn't returning any record. Any ideas?"* Because `where product='Fruit' AND product='Chocolate'` can **never** be true. If `product` has the value `'Fruit'` it therefore , by definition, doesn't have the value `'Chocolate'`, and hence you get no rows. A scalar value cannot have 2 different scalar value simultaneously.

Comment: Note, _columns_, not fields. _Row_, not record.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can try to write aggregate condition function in `HAVING`

```
SELECT ID,purchase_date    
FROM dbo.mytable
GROUP BY  ID,purchase_date    
HAVING 
    COUNT(CASE WHEN product='Fruit' THEN 1 END) > 0 
AND
    COUNT(CASE WHEN product='Chocolate' THEN 1 END) > 0
```

Comment: Do you kow how I can change it to just find people who only bought fruit and nothing else? @D-Shih

Comment: You can try to create a table which represent product of fruit ( or add a flag to represent) then use `join` or `where` to filter it.

Comment: moreover, I will suggest you create a new thread and provide more detail about that. because it seem like another question

Answer (score 3):

One method would be to use a conditional `COUNT` in the `HAVING`:

```sql
SELECT ID,
       Purchase_date
FROM dbo.MyTable
GROUP BY ID,
         Purchase_date
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN product IN ('Fruit','Chocolate') THEN product END) = 2;
```

Answer (score 2):

And yet another option since many people seem to ignore or forget about set operators.

```
select ID, purchase_date from dbo.mytable where product='Fruit' 
intersect
select ID, purchase_date from dbo.mytable where product='Chocolate';
```

Notice the lack of an ORDER BY clause. If order matters (and usually it does), then you must include an ORDER BY clause.

Answer (score 1):

your data

```
declare @a TABLE (
   ID            int  NOT NULL 
  ,purchase_date DATE  NOT NULL
  ,product       VARCHAR(9) NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO @a(ID,purchase_date,product) VALUES (22212,'2021-06-03','Fruit');
INSERT INTO @a(ID,purchase_date,product) VALUES (111999,'2021-06-03','Fruit');
INSERT INTO @a(ID,purchase_date,product) VALUES (111999,'2021-06-03','Chocolate');
INSERT INTO @a(ID,purchase_date,product) VALUES (56727,'2019-05-03','Bread');
INSERT INTO @a(ID,purchase_date,product) VALUES (30726,'2019-05-03','Fruit');
INSERT INTO @a(ID,purchase_date,product) VALUES (30761,'2019-05-03','Chocolate');
INSERT INTO @a(ID,purchase_date,product) VALUES (53899,'2019-05-03','Fruit');
```

your final query

```
with t as(
select ID, purchase_date,STRING_AGG( product,',') products  from @a
group by ID,purchase_date)

select ID,purchase_date from t
where products like N'%Chocolate%' and  products like N'%Fruit%'
```